# Persistence of a PostgreSQL visibility map through RDS snapshot and restore

Tags: postgresql, snapshot, amazon-rds

I have a pretty huge (1,2 TB) DB on a big RDS PostgreSQL 9.6.1 instance (db.m4.4xlarge). The DB is static (no on-line transactions) and we are testing performance of scripts (mainly analytical queries).

The DB was built from a plaintext SQL scripts backup (`CREATE TABLE` + `COPY`), so it has no dead tuples. After the restore, I ran just a complete `ANALYZE` (not a `VACUUM`).

After the `ANALYZE`, I saved the DB in a snapshot and deleted the instance.
I would like to start often from that snapshot as a known and stable test bed.

I noticed that the first execution of scripts (e.g. `select count(*) from table`) after the restore from that snapshot is way too long (i.e. 50min for `count(*)` of a 116 mln rows table). The subsequent execution of the same query lasts around 15 sec.

It seems to me that 50 minutes can't be explained by the reading of table from SSD instead of RAM cache.

I discovered that visibility map of all tables after the restore+analyze+snapshot wasn't compiled  (`SELECT ... relpages, relallvisible FROM pg_class...`), and the first execution of the query had to do the job of compiling it.

So I ran a complete `VACUUM ANALYZE`. I saw the performance improvement in the query and took a new snapshot, aiming to save a better test bed (I haven't found documentation about persistence of visibility map in PostgreSQL backups or in RDS snapshots).

Unfortunately I discovered that, after taking snapshot and restoring from it, first execution is still long (no improvement). Visibility map seems to be lost, despite the (`SELECT ... relpages, relallvisible FROM pg_class...`) showing good values for `relallvisible`.

Are my findings wrong?

There is a way to have persistence of the visibility map through a RDS snapshot and restore?

There is a documentation to study useful for this aim?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, RDS snapshots are stored on S3. When an RDS snapshot is restored into a new instance, the instance becomes ready to use before all of the snapshot blocks have been copied from S3 to the disk of the new instance.

The instance operates a read through cache - the first time each block is accessed and it's not on the instance yet, it will be fetched from S3. This makes the IO times appear relatively slow, but subsequent queries that access that block will have fast IO.

If you  want to perform tests on the instance and get consistent performance, you could use the [pg_prewarm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/pgprewarm.html) to read every block and ensure it's been fetched from S3.